# Dynamic variable names in Swift

Tags: macos, swift

I would like to refer to a variable in swift using a combination of a string and another variable. In php I would often do the following:

```
$i = 1
${'variable' . $i} = 'test'
```

Which is the same as

```
$variable1 = 'test'
```

How is this done in Swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't.** Unlike PHP, Swift is not an interpreted language. As of version 1.1 it doesn't support almost any dynamism (which is a cost for being safe and performant).